# Avoid try/catch at every call site, in favor of single place

Tags: java, exception, lambda, try-catch

I have a bunch of Java methods that I can modify as I please. Let us call this group of methods for B.

Then I have some auto-generated Java code that calls methods in B. Let us call this code for A.

The B code calls methods in some other auto-generated code. Let us call this code for C.

So call flow is: A -> B -> C, of which I can only modify B methods.

The C methods may throw exceptions that I want to catch at B.

My exception handling is the same for all C methods.

I could duplicate my try-catch block at every call site in B calling a C method. But I have hundreds of methods and so I would like to keep common exception handling in a single place.

An idea is to put C-calls in lambdas, and then pass the lambda to a common invoke(lambda) method which can execute the lambda in a try-catch block.

Any other ideas?

regards
Mark

Comment: are there multiple threads involved?

Comment: Java won't have lambdas before Java 8. You could use an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), but that would probably be as verbose as wrapping the C call into a try-catch block invoking a common method in the cacth block, unless you have several different catch blocks.

Comment: Yes of course. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Jack You can assume single threaded.

Comment: Is C an interface? If yes, you could use a (dynamic) proxy, which does the error handling. If not, I think it's still possible - but with a lot more of black magic (mocking tools) involved.

Comment: @tilois Nope. Very much concrete methods.

Comment: Since you're already generating code, why don't you generate a CWrapper class that calls C and handles its exceptions?

Comment: @JBNizet I don't control the generator :/

Comment: Is `A` hardwired against `B`? Do the exceptions from `C` have a common base class?

Comment: @tilois A calls B, so yes, A is hardwired to B. And yes C exceptions do have a common base. I am thinking more and more of using anonymous classes with interface for each return type.

Comment: `A` is autogenerated, it is hardwired to `B`. That means that if `B` changes, the autogenerated code in `A` will be invalid. You've said that you have full control over `B`, so I assume you have access to the generator of `A`. That means, you can generate your error handling code there?

Comment: You can use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch everything on that thread which can catch just the required exceptions or forward them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Using lambdas is OK, though, then you shouldn't forget to use those lambdas each time. It might be problematic on a project which is developed by many programmers because each programmer should be aware of this.

Another solution can be [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). You will need to use some framework for this, for example [Guice](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.hu/2009/01/guice-tutorial-part-2-method.html), Spring or something else.

In case of AOP, try-catch blocks will be applied automatically on runtime. (If you set up the extension points and the interceptors accordingly of course.) Probably there are some AOP tools which change the bytecode at compile time.